# How to add Slideshow control in HTML within an iOS UIWebView?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, uiwebview

I have an iOS project with Client server communication. In one particular webservice response, I get html string as a response which I am rendering to a UIWebView.
What I want to do now is to show a slideshow of a few images in between the html content. Basically, I would like to edit the html string which I get as a response and insert the slideshow control in the HTML.
I have heard of jQuery carousel which can be used for this slide show control, but have never used it.

I would appreciate if anyone can tell me if what I am trying to achieve is possible at all or not. If yes, what would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show an HTML slideshow, you may want to use a jQuery plugin or something else. When you will receive the HTML response, the UIWebView will show it without any problem.
However, you can do with native code, but I think you manage the responses to be seen on a WebView...